# Binary Patching - modifing existing instructions and keeping machine code alignment

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

I'd like to edit the first instruction and change it to `jmp 100h` (give or take a few bytes)
the `mov edi,edi` takes 2 bytes and the `jmp 100h` takes 5 bytes (correct me if im wrong)

I edit the machine code to `jmp 100h` and add a `nop` to round it to 6 bytes.

```
.text:08048DD5                 mov     edi, edi
.text:08048DD7                 mov     edi, edi
.text:08048DD9                 mov     edi, edi
.text:08048DDB                 mov     edi, edi
.text:08048DDD                 mov     edi, edi
.text:08048DDF                 mov     edi, edi
.text:08048DE1                 mov     edi, edi
.text:08048DE3                 mov     edi, edi
.text:08048DE5                 add     [ebp+var_C], 1  ; Add
.text:08048DE9                 mov     eax, offset format ; "Message %d: %s"
.text:08048DEE                 lea     edx, [ebp+s]    ; Load Effective Address
.text:08048DF4                 mov     [esp+8], edx
```

the result looks like:

```
.text:08048DD5                 jmp     loc_8048D41
.text:08048DD5 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:08048DDA                 db 90h
.text:08048DDB                 db 89h, 0FFh
.text:08048DDD                 db 89h, 0FFh
.text:08048DDF                 db 89h, 0FFh
.text:08048DE1                 db 89h, 0FFh
.text:08048DE3                 db 89h, 0FFh
.text:08048DE5 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:08048DE5                 add     [ebp+var_C], 1
.text:08048DE9                 mov     eax, offset aMessageDS ; "Message %d: %s"
.text:08048DEE                 lea     edx, [ebp+s]
.text:08048DF4                 mov     [esp+8], edx
.text:08048DF8                 mov     edx, [ebp+var_C]
```

what exactly goes wrong here? How do i keep the rest of the code intact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it works, but the disassembler isn't interpreting the data as instructions. This is probably because of the preceding `jmp` instruction - the disassembler sees that the code right after it will never be reached, so it assumes it's not actually code (and thus interprets it as straight data).

Comment: The `90h` is `nop` and the `89h, 0FFh` is `mov edi, edi` so yes it has worked correctly.